# Problem with a column name contains a colon in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, geospatial, postgis, shapefile, geoserver

I downloaded the shape data from OSM.
I have imported data from Shapefile into PostgreSQL without any problem but I got an error when I do the select statement.

```
Select addr:city From location;

Error: syntax error at or near ":"
```

The problem is because of the column name contains a colon.
Could anyone help me with this issue?
Should I reject this shapefile in the importing process?
Is the shapefile normal?

Comment: SELECT 'addr:city' FROM location     might do the trick

Comment: @Nick : This would select the string 'addr:city', not the column. You want to use double quote in this case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you enclose `addr:city` with quotes it should work:

```
SELECT "addr:city" FROM "location";
```

And if you want to use OpenStreetMap data, you don't have to import shapefiles. Instead, you can import planet.osm (or a regional subset) directly with [osm2pgsql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql).